# not able to downgrade matplotlib from version 3.1.1 to 3.1.0

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using anaconda environment for learning data science. 
I currently have matplotlib version 3.1.1 installed in my anaconda.
I am trying to downgrade it to version 3.1.0 using `pip install matplotlib==3.1.0` in windows but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\__pycache__\\pylab.cpython-37.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Can anyone help me in dealing with this problem

Comment: Why are you using pip for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run cmd as administrator and then try to install..

If that does't work..

Just type the command you want execute with the user permission, if you don't want to change the permission:

```
pip install matplotlib==3.1.0 --user
```

Comment: thank u so much this worked. I have successfully downgraded to versin 3.1.0

Answer (score 2):

You are using Anaconda, which comes with it's own package manager `conda`.

To solve the problem, open a command prompt with administrator privileges
and enter this command:

```
conda install matplotlib==3.1.0
```